# cannot connect service running on remote computer

Tags: java, maven, curl

I bulid a jersey restful server using maven. After I issued the command  `mvn exec:java`, the server runs successfully listening on `port 8080`. Assume that the server process is executed on `machine A` (Machine A have installed Ubuntu server OS and Its IP is `10.131.252.248`).

I then type the command on machine A :

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/myresource/getGoalModelList
```

I get the return value successfully.

Then, I execute the command again using another style on Machine A.

`$ curl http://10.131.252.248:8080/myapp/myresource/getGoalModelList`

`10.131.252.248` is IP of machine A. But I cannot get anything and the commmand
screen shows: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.131.252.248 port 8080: Connection refused.`

when I send the same get request `http://10.131.252.248:8080/myapp/myresource/getGoalModelList`

through brower on machine B on which win 8.1 OS operates. It also fail to get the expected result. why?

Comment: Is port 8080 opened on your machine?

Comment: CHeck firewall. Do a `netstat -na | grep 8080` on your linux box. Share the results

Comment: Most probably a firewall running on the 10.131.252.248 machine, not allowing connections to port 8080 from outside (only localhost).

Comment: @jan  the result is ---> “ tcp6  0  0  127.0.0.1:8080  :::*  LISTEN ”. what does it mean

Comment: @Jozef how to solve it when a firewall running on the machine preventing other machine from connecting on port 8080.

Comment: @Jean  yes, 8080 is using by jersey server.

Comment: You're Jersey server listens on **localhost** only - so no wonder you cannot connect from the outside. Can you share the code to setup your server? You should bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Jan  Great !!! Thank you. It works when I bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.  But I don't know why it can work after such modification.

Comment: Might I add that as answer?

Comment: yes , absolutely. @Jan

Comment: Did so. You're free to upvote and accept ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `netstat -na | grep 8080` showed:

```
 tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8080 :::* LISTEN
```

You were binding your server to 127.0.0.1 That's localhost only. So only connections comming from the same machine will be able to see that port. On your oudside interface (say 192.168.1.1) the port is not bound - so no connections possible to that.

By binding to `0.0.0.0` you specify **bind to *all* available interfaces** - so your port is now visible not only to `127.0.0.1` but to your outside connections as well.